# Editing PHAR files

Tags: php, phar

I'm trying to edit a phar file and I understand that it doesn't support incremental updates and that I have to extract the phar file, edit its contents and then compress it again to be able to use it.

I'm having trouble understanding how to extract phar files. A simple how-to would be much appreciated. I'm currently on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just open the Phar and do what you want

```
$phar = new Phar($filename);
```